# Running Propeller in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, graphics, rotation

I have a problem with a task that I have. The task is to make a spinning fan in C#. I've drawn the fan but when I try to move it everything breaks down. I read quite a few topics on the matter but I couldn't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

This is how I draw the 4 blades of the fan:

```
public void OnTimer(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {

                    Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();
                    drawBlade(g, angle);
                    drawBlade(g, angle + 90);
                    drawBlade(g, angle + 180);
                    drawBlade(g, angle + 270);
                    g.Dispose();


            }
```

I try to rotate them with a timer but it results in blinking blades and no change of position. So I need to find a way to make them move smoothly in a circle around the center of the ellipse that I use for a border.

This is the drawBlade function:

```
public void drawBlade(Graphics g, float angle)
        {

            g.FillPie(Brushes.Black, xCenter - bladeLength, yCenter - bladeLength, 2 * bladeLength, 2 * bladeLength, angle, 30);
        }
```

Thank you beforehand!

Comment: You should show your drawBlade function, what you have has no apparent errors. Also show where you modify/track the angle variable.

Comment: Also, don't use "this.CreateGraphics", use a bitmap and update that.

Comment: so you want the propeller to both turn and move in a circle? If so, where in your code is the movement? Also to look like a turning propeller it shouldn't just jump by 90° but in small angles using RotateTransform!

Comment: angle = (angle + direction) / 360;
This is how I modify the angle variable. angle is set to 100 and direction is set to 1

Answer (score 0):

First of all i really do not think that there is a problem with your code. Unfortunately, there is a problem with how your drawing is perceived. You have to move the blades at least 18 times (frames) per second for the movement to be registered as a rotational movement. The previous suggestion to use a bitmap instead of drawing the blades is useful because you can create the rotation effect in the drawing software( by simply rotating the entire fan once drawn with a small angle) and storing that image for later display. Now for the move to register to the human eye, it has to last a few milliseconds on the screen before it gets changed.So if you draw a fan rotating add a small delay,20-50ms between redrawing of the fan blades or image. Also to create the illusion of move, you have to have several "intermediary" positions between "key" positions. That might sound confusing but i will explain myself. In your 4 blade setup, you have unfortunately only one key position with the blades at 90 degrees one from each other at 12,3,6 and 9. In order to create the illusion of movement you have to create at least 3 intermediary positions at at least 7 degrees apart from each other for the movement to register. So my recommendation would be to split the 90 degree space in 3( i would recommend 5) intermediary positions, they do not have to be uniform, draw the blades in those positions, respect the show interval and you will have the illusion of rotation. If you go down the path of drawing the blades, do not forget to delete the previous drawing before painting the new one.

Comment: That's quite a leap to make without seeing the animation code.

Comment: Any decent gaming package has something called sprites. he can start drawing his animation in a similar way. it's not rocket science. It's old school eye fooling technique. 18 FPS is the lowest frequency you can use to display static pictures in a sequence and the result is perceived by the human eye as motion. Anything lower than that is viewed as individual pictures or if displayed to fast as garbage. they do not even register.

Comment: The OP is using Winforms, and of course it's not rocket science. All I'm saying is can't possibly know that your explanation applies to the OP's problem.

Comment: Ok. symptom: blinking blades but no impression of movement. The most likely cause, angle is always incremented in 90 degrees and there are 4 blades. result is blinking but no movement. He has the drawing in an onTimer event so i assume the OP figured out already that he needs to wait a little before moving to the next draw. Most probably the interval is small enough to be perceived as a blink but not as a move. All i did was get the symptoms and the drawing code and assumed.. if my assumption is wrong then the OP must clarify further.